# No such file When JSch mkdir is called

Tags: java, io, jsch

I am attempting to create folder inside sftp directory. But below exception is occurs when creating folder by using below code.

> 2: No such file   at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2289)
>     at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.mkdir(ChannelSftp.java:1699)

Below one is not creating directory :

```
channelSftp.mkdir("/root/work/file/01/");
```

Below one is creating directory :

```
channelSftp.mkdir("/root/work/file/");
```

In server already have directory **/root/work/**

How to create multiple sub folder in one line using jsch. Please advice me.

Comment: the java doc states for the `path` variable of `mkdir`: `path - the path of the new directory, relative to the current remote directory.` Your path looks absolute.

Comment: @HerrDerb Absolute path is perfectly valid, everywhere, where a relative path can be used. Absolute path is a path that has an absolute meaning *relatively* to any other path.

Comment: There's no way to *"create multiple sub folders in one line using jsch"*.